# How to read/write bytes using QDataStream in PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I'm trying to read and write raw data to a QDataStream so I can serialize data for custom widgets, but in PySide6 there seems to be an issue where the documentation wrongly states that functions `QDataStream::readBytes` and `QDataStream::writeBytes` both exist, which they don't?

So naturally I try to use the ones that do exist, `QDataStream::readRawData` and `QDataStream::writeRawData`. The issue is that the documentation says the signatures are `readRawData(length: int) -> bytes` and `writeRawData(data: bytes) -> None`.

When you call the functions as the documentation suggests, it throws a TypeError because the C++ binding and native Qt signatures call for 2 arguments each, making them `readRawData(out: bytes, length: int) -> None` and `writeRawData(data: bytes, length: int) -> None` instead (Matching the C++ counterparts, and also matching the type stub files)?

Example error:

```
...
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtCore.QDataStream.writeRawData' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtCore.QDataStream.writeRawData(bytes)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtCore.QDataStream.writeRawData(bytes, int)
```

So, I naturally tried to call them following this signature, but when I do Python throws a TypeError stating I've not called them with the right amount of arguments

Example Error:

```
...
    out.writeRawData(rawData, length)
TypeError: QDataStream.writeRawData() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I'm not sure what to do, I can't satisfy the requirements here. If anyone knows what's up please let me know, this is really peaking my curiosity. If I need to use PyQt6 instead I can do that too.

Comment: It seems that those methods were not exposed in PySide (as opposite to PyQt), as also suggested by [this report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-890). In the meantime, you can use the `<<` and `>>` operators.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for me. Very strange that PySide isn't exposing these methods (and leaving the rawData methods in this broken state), but I suppose those are superficial issues as long as the operators work.

Comment: The `>>` and `<<` operator are the "readBytes" and "writeBytes" methods in Qt, which will prefix the bytes with its length as uint32. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatastream.html#writeBytes